# How to improve this model with hyperparameter tuning

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, knn

I am building machine learning model for titanic dataset using KNN algorithm.I have divided the data as train,validation and test with 70%,15% and 15% respectively.I have used GridSearch CV and RandomizedsearchCV to find best hyperparameters but still the accuracy of the test set is 56%. Is there any way to improve the accuracy of the model using KNN?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype,is_numeric_dtype
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score,matthews_corrcoef,f1_score
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import joblib

get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')


# In[2]:


get_ipython().run_line_magic('pwd', '')


# In[3]:


my_path = '/Users/kiran/DataScience'


# In[4]:


get_ipython().run_line_magic('pwd', '')


# In[5]:


my_df = pd.read_csv(f'{my_path}/Titanic_full.csv')


# In[6]:


print(my_df.shape)


# In[7]:


my_df.head(3)


# In[8]:


print(my_df.shape)


# In[9]:


#Splitting the data by writing a fucntion

def mydf_splitter(my_df,num_rows):
    return my_df[:num_rows].copy(),my_df[num_rows:]

mydf_train_valid,mydf_test = mydf_splitter(my_df,1100)

print(mydf_train_valid.shape,mydf_test.shape)


# In[10]:


print(len(mydf_train_valid))


# In[11]:


print(mydf_train_valid.isnull().sum())


# In[12]:


null_vals = mydf_train_valid.isnull().sum()/len(mydf_train_valid)
null_vals = pd.DataFrame(null_vals)
null_vals.reset_index(inplace=True)
null_vals.columns = ["Feature","Percent missing"]
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
sns.barplot(x="Feature",y="Percent missing",data=null_vals)


# In[13]:


mydf_train_valid_2 = mydf_train_valid.drop("Cabin",axis = 1)
print(mydf_train_valid_2.shape)
mydf_train_valid_2.head(2)


# In[14]:


mydf_train_valid_2.info()


# In[15]:


def str_to_cat(my_df):
    for p,q in my_df.items():
        if is_string_dtype(q):
            my_df[p] = q.astype('category').cat.as_ordered()
    return my_df


# In[16]:


mydf_train_valid_3 = str_to_cat(mydf_train_valid_2)
mydf_train_valid_3.info()


# In[17]:


#Check category mapping of Embarked and Sex columns

print(mydf_train_valid_3.Embarked.cat.categories)
print(mydf_train_valid_3.Sex.cat.categories)


# In[18]:


#categorical missing values function
def mydf_to_nums(my_df,feature,null_status):
    if not is_numeric_dtype(feature):
        my_df[null_status] = feature.cat.codes+1;

def mydf_imputer(my_df, feature, null_status, null_table):
    if is_numeric_dtype(feature):
        if pd.isnull(feature).sum() or (null_status in null_table):
            my_df[null_status+'_na'] = pd.isnull(feature)
            filler = null_table[null_status] if null_status in null_table else feature.median()
            my_df[null_status] = feature.fillna(filler)
            null_table[null_status] = filler
    return null_table 

def mydf_preprocessor(my_df,null_table):
    if null_table is None:
        null_table = dict()
    for p,q in my_df.items():
        null_table = mydf_imputer(my_df,q,p,null_table)
    for p,q in my_df.items():
        mydf_to_nums(my_df,q,p)
    my_df = pd.get_dummies(my_df,dummy_na = True)
    res = [my_df, null_table]
    return res;


# In[19]:


mydf_train_valid_4,my_table = mydf_preprocessor(mydf_train_valid_3,null_table = None)


# In[20]:


mydf_train_valid_4.head(3)


# In[21]:


my_table


# In[22]:


Y = mydf_train_valid_4["Survived"]
X = mydf_train_valid_4.drop(["Survived"],axis = 1)

print(X.shape,Y.shape)


# In[23]:


#Scale the continuous value so seperate continuous and categorical value
X_cat = X[['PassengerId', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'SibSp', 'Parch',
       'Ticket', 'Embarked', 'Age_na', 'Fare_na']]
X_con = X.drop(X_cat,axis = 1)
print(X_cat.shape,X_con.shape)


# In[24]:


#Scale the data
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_con)
X_con_sc = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(X_con))
X_con_sc.columns = ["Age","Fare"]
print(X_con_sc.shape)
X_con_sc.head(2)


# In[25]:


#Store the scalar variable and categorical value for test data
df_list = [X_cat,X_con_sc]
X_full = pd.concat(df_list,axis = 1)
print(X_full.shape)
X_full.head(2)


# In[26]:


X_train,X_valid = mydf_splitter(X_full,900)
Y_train,Y_valid = mydf_splitter(Y,900)

print(X_train.shape,X_valid.shape,Y_train.shape,Y_valid.shape)


# In[27]:


#Build the classifier model
my_knn_model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5,weights='uniform')
my_knn_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)

#Predict on the validation set
Y_pred = my_knn_model.predict(X_valid)


# In[68]:


#Plot confusion matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

my_knn_cmatrix = confusion_matrix(Y_valid,Y_pred)

my_knn_df = pd.DataFrame(my_knn_cmatrix)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
sns.heatmap(my_knn_df,xticklabels=["Unlucky","Survived"],
           yticklabels=["Unlucky","Survived"],annot=True)


# In[ ]:





# In[69]:


print(accuracy_score(Y_valid,Y_pred),
      matthews_corrcoef(Y_valid,Y_pred),f1_score(Y_valid,Y_pred))


# In[70]:


import imblearn
print(imblearn.__version__)
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from collections import Counter


# In[71]:


oversample = SMOTE()
X_train, Y_train = oversample.fit_resample(X_train, Y_train)
counter = Counter(Y_train)
print(counter)


# In[78]:


#Build the classifier model
my_knn_model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5,weights='uniform')
my_knn_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)

#Predict on the validation set
Y_pred = my_knn_model.predict(X_valid)


# In[79]:


#Plot confusion matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

my_knn_cmatrix = confusion_matrix(Y_valid,Y_pred)

my_knn_df = pd.DataFrame(my_knn_cmatrix)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
sns.heatmap(my_knn_df,xticklabels=["Unlucky","Survived"],
           yticklabels=["Unlucky","Survived"],annot=True)


# In[82]:




print(accuracy_score(Y_valid,Y_pred),
      matthews_corrcoef(Y_valid,Y_pred),f1_score(Y_valid,Y_pred))


# In[ ]:





# In[ ]:





# # Got the accuracy score 54%

# # Hyper Parameter Tuning

# #  Using RandomizedSearchCV

# In[84]:


from sklearn.model_selection import  RandomizedSearchCV
import numpy as np
k_range = np.arange(1,31)
weights = ["uniform","distance"]
p = [1,2]
metric=['minkowski','euclidean','manhattan']
leaf_size = list(range(1,50))
metric_params = dict
metric_params = None
n_jobs = None
param_grid = dict(n_neighbors = k_range, weights = weights,p=p,metric = metric,leaf_size=leaf_size)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
randomized = RandomizedSearchCV(knn, param_grid,scoring = "accuracy", cv = 10, n_iter = 10)


# In[85]:


randomized.fit(X_train,Y_train)


# In[86]:


randomized.best_estimator_


# In[87]:


randomized.cv_results_


# In[88]:


randomized.best_params_


# In[89]:


#Randomized Search CV is able to find the best accuracy.
randomized.best_score_


# #  Building the model with tuned parameters

# In[90]:


#Build the classifier model
my_knn_model = KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=47, metric='manhattan',
                     metric_params=None, n_jobs=None, n_neighbors=1, p=1,
                     weights='uniform')
my_knn_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)

#Predict on the validation set
Y_pred = my_knn_model.predict(X_valid)


# In[91]:


#Plot confusion matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

my_knn_cmatrix = confusion_matrix(Y_valid,Y_pred)

my_knn_df = pd.DataFrame(my_knn_cmatrix)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
sns.heatmap(my_knn_df,xticklabels=["Unlucky","Survived"],
           yticklabels=["Unlucky","Survived"],annot=True)


# In[93]:


print(accuracy_score(Y_valid,Y_pred),
      matthews_corrcoef(Y_valid,Y_pred),f1_score(Y_valid,Y_pred))


# In[ ]:





# In[94]:


from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

num_neighs = list()
accuracy_list = list()


for neighbor in range(1,30):
    my_knn_model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=neighbor,weights='uniform',p=1,metric='manhattan',leaf_size = 47)
    my_knn_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
    Y_pred = my_knn_model.predict(X_valid)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(Y_valid,Y_pred)
    num_neighs.append(neighbor)
    accuracy_list.append(accuracy)


# In[95]:


eval_df = pd.DataFrame({"Num of neighbors":num_neighs,"Valid accuracy Score":accuracy_list})
eval_df


# In[96]:


sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.pairplot(eval_df,x_vars="Num of neighbors",
            y_vars = "Valid accuracy Score",plot_kws={'s':60},height=4.0)


# In[97]:


#For K=25

knn_model_fin = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3,weights='uniform',p=1,metric='manhattan',leaf_size = 47)
knn_model_fin.fit(X_full,Y)

#!mkdir knn_model
knn_model_name1 = f'{my_path}/knn_model/knn_model_final1.sav'
joblib.dump(knn_model_fin,knn_model_name1)


# In[98]:


knn_model_loaded = joblib.load(knn_model_name1)


# In[99]:


#Evaluating test set accuracy with the trained model
mydf_test1 = mydf_test.drop("Cabin",axis = 1)
print(mydf_test1.shape)
mydf_test1.head(3)


# In[100]:


mydf_test2 = str_to_cat(mydf_test1)
mydf_test2.Sex.cat.categories


# In[101]:


#Check for the Embarked column
mydf_test2.Embarked.cat.categories


# In[102]:


mydf_test3,my_table1 = mydf_preprocessor(mydf_test2,
                                        null_table = my_table)
print(mydf_test3.shape)
mydf_test3.head(3)


# In[103]:


my_table1


# In[104]:


Y_t = mydf_test3["Survived"]
X_t = mydf_test3.drop(["Survived"],axis = 1)

print(X_t.shape,Y_t.shape)


# In[105]:


X_cat_t = X_t[['PassengerId', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'SibSp', 'Parch',
       'Ticket', 'Embarked', 'Age_na', 'Fare_na']]
X_con_t = X_t.drop(X_cat_t,axis = 1)
print(X_cat_t.shape,X_con_t.shape)


# In[106]:


X_con_sct = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(X_con_t))
X_con_sct.columns = ["Age","Fare"]
print(X_con_sct.shape)
X_con_sct.head(2)


# In[107]:


print(X_cat_t.shape,X_con_sct.shape)


# In[108]:


X_cat_t.head()


# In[109]:


#Re-index before merging
X_cat_t.reset_index(inplace = True,drop = False)


# In[110]:


X_cat_t.drop("index",inplace = True,axis = 1)
X_cat_t.head(2)


# In[111]:


#Merge the two sets of columns
df_list_I = [X_cat_t,X_con_sct]
X_test_I = pd.concat(df_list_I,axis = 1)
print(X_test_I.shape)
X_test_I.head(3)


# In[112]:


#Now we are ready to test it out. Let's load the saved model first.
kNN_loaded = joblib.load(f'{my_path}/knn_model/knn_model_final1.sav')


# In[113]:


#Testing...
Y_test_pred = kNN_loaded.predict(X_test_I)


# In[114]:


print(accuracy_score(Y_t,Y_test_pred),
      matthews_corrcoef(Y_t,Y_test_pred),f1_score(Y_t,Y_test_pred))


# In[ ]:





# In[ ]:





# In[ ]:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a data science question so you might consider moving your question to [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

That being said, I would encourage you to do some more feature engineering or select a subset of features that might be more important than others since it looks like you are weighting everything the same. Hypothetically speaking, if one or more variables have no correlation to the target, then using KNN and weighting these variables as having the same importance as others can lead to a suboptimal model. Since you are using the sklearn library, [SelectKBest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html) might be a useful place to start.

56% accuracy is on the lower side, so I wouldn't have bothered with hyperparameter tuning until the model is performing better (but since you have already implemented it, feel free to leave it as it can't hurt). Realistically hyperparameter tuning will only give you at most a small boost to the performance of your model.